# Single-page application with jsp mvc

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp, single-page-application, web-frontend

I'm pretty new to Angular and jsp and I have a question about general architecture of a single-page system.
I understand that jsp mvc has it's own security features that some of course related to conditionally delivering static/dynamic pages to the clients.

How can that feature work with Angular? Obviously in a single page application, working with partials, the server does not need to pass pages to the client.

My specific question is about the login page. Do I need to separate my login html from my main 'single-page' index.html with all my routes?
Will I have a 'login.jsp' file which is a stand-alone file handled by jsp and only after login routing to the single-page part of the application?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the login part:

My recommendation is that as an application developer you should not be thinking in how to implement your login page. This would bind your application to a specific authentication mechanism, and its a sign of getting into troubles (implementing the whole app security by your own)

It is preferable that this binding is performed in a pluggable (declarative) way, like it is done in [JEE](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-webtier002.htm) by the container or in [Spring security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) by a dedicated framework.

So answering your question: you should no have a `login.jsp` at all, this page would be automatically generated once you have properly configured your application security with a 'login form' authentication mechanism. (Both JEE and Spring provide also mechanisms for customizing this pages).

The framework/container would intercept the request to your web app, identify if the user is authenticated, redirect to the login page and finally redirect to the original url, if authentication succeeds.

Cheers,
Nacho